# Views ajax not enabling

Tags: 7, views

i'm trying to use an exposed filter with my views but i'm not getting my ajax to enable under the advanced link so my content can be dynamic. I try jquery update module to fix it but didn't work tried another browser didn't work too i really need help here...

Answer (score 0):

The "use ajax" checkbox in Views refers to the pager only. Any other magic you may want to work with ajax would require some custom code or additional modules, depending on what you're doing.